# Sort MYSQL SELECT in the order of related to the CHILD entry

Tags: mysql

I have database table with parent and child entries. Ex.

```
+---+-------+-------+---------+
|id |title  |parent | added   |
+---+-------+-------+---------+
|1  |title1 |0      |09:50    |
|2  |title2 |0      |09:55    |
|3  |title3 |0      |10:00    |
|4  |title4 |3      |10:05    |
|5  |title5 |1      |10:10    |
|6  |title6 |2      |10:15    |
+---+-------+-------+---------+
```

I need to select only `parent = 0` but in the order of latest child entry added to the table.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent=0 ORDER BY added DESC`

this only gives me following output

```
+---+-------+-------+---------+
|id |title  |parent | added   |
+---+-------+-------+---------+
|3  |title3 |0      |10:00    |
|2  |title2 |0      |09:55    |
|1  |title1 |0      |09:50    |
+---+-------+-------+---------+
```

But since id 4, 5, 6 added in related to parent order is 2, 1, 3 so my expectation is

```
+---+-------+-------+---------+
|id |title  |parent | added   |
+---+-------+-------+---------+
|2  |title2 |0      |09:55    |
|1  |title1 |0      |09:50    |
|3  |title3 |0      |10:00    |
+---+-------+-------+---------+
```

What is the best way of writing this script?

FYI. Sorry for my poor English. If anyone can write this better way you are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 2):

If a parent can only have one child, you can do this with a simple `LEFT JOIN` to the children and then ordering the result by the child `added` value:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
WHERE t1.parent = 0
ORDER BY t2.added DESC
```

Output

```
id  title   parent  added
2   title2  0       09:55
1   title1  0       09:50
3   title3  0       10:00
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c2386/2)

If a parent may have multiple children, you will need to find the `MAX(added)` for the children of each parent and sort by that instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent, MAX(added) AS added 
           FROM table1 t2 
           GROUP BY parent) t2
    ON t2.parent = t1.id
WHERE t1.parent = 0
ORDER BY t2.added DESC
```

[Alternate demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70b712/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try in following way

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TABLE T1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ID,parent
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE parent=0) T2 ON T1.parent = T2.ID
ORDER BY T1.added DESC


//Output

id  title   parent  added   
6   title6  2       10:15   
5   title5  1       10:10   
4   title4  3       10:05
```